# and (&&) logic in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, logic, swift4

I have problem with the (&&) logic in swift, I don't understand why the compiler deal with 'and' logic as 'or' logic, I enter one field and he ignore the others

```
   if (self.txtAddressNickname.text!.isEmpty == true) && (self.txtArea.text!.isEmpty == 
  true) && (self.txtHouseNo.text.isEmpty == true) && (self.txtAddressType.text!.isEmpty 
  == true) && (self.txtStreet.text!.isEmpty == true) && (self.txtHouseNo.text!.isEmpty 
  == true) && (self.txtMobileNo.text!.isEmpty == true){

     // alert

        }
```

Comment: you want to show the alert message if any one textfield is empty?

Comment: What do you want your code to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show an alert if any of the fields is empty, right?

You need 'or', not 'and'.

```
 if txtAddressNickname.text!.isEmpty || 
    txtArea.text!.isEmpty  || 
    txtHouseNo.text.isEmpty || 
    txtAddressType.text!.isEmpty || 
    txtStreet.text!.isEmpty || 
    txtHouseNo.text!.isEmpty || 
    txtMobileNo.text!.isEmpty {

        // alert

    }
```

I also tidy your code up little bit to read more easly.

Comment: If tidying up, you should also consider throwing out all the `== true`: a boolean `x` is equivalent to `x == true`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also 'self.' part should be removed. But I did not want to change the code too much, so the questioner can understand easily.

Comment: Good point! Then I'd include both what you have currently and more clean code.

Comment: And here we go. You mean, the original code should stay as a part of answer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

**`&&` works like:**

If 1 condition on the way give `false`, compiler won't check the further conditions in the expression.

**Similarly, `||` works like,**

If 1 condition on the way give `true`, compiler won't check the further conditions in the expression.

So, in your expression any of the initial `textField` might be empty, so it is not checking further.

Answer (score 0):

AND and OR logic is the same in all programming languages.
**A and B** is true only if A is true and B is true.
**A or B** is true if A is true or B is true or both of them are true.
Check the images below, note that 0 is false and 1 is true : 
[image]     [image]